# How do I install the newest unstable NodeJS (e.g. 0.11.xyz) on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking into playing around with Koa and I need to run the newest unstable version of NodeJS.

Is there a simple `apt-get` or `npm` or even `node` call I can make to get the newest NodeJS version?

Comment: You can either clone it from the GH repo or from nodejs.org and make it, install nvm (node version manager) or add a repository with it installed, all are rather easy.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thank you very much, nvm is exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to the NodeJS eco system and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 users should find [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) helpful in getting started with both ```node``` and ```nvm```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), or another node version manager, such as [n](https://github.com/tj/n), which has less [github stars](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/stargazers), but it was released later, it can be installed with just npm: `npm install -g n`, and it contains a simpler api.

(Below substitute `nvm install` with `n`. The other commands are identical just substitute `nvm` for `n`.)

[NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) has a remote command line install script:

```
`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.20.0/install.sh | bash`
```

Or clone the repo `$ git clone creationix/nvm`

Then add to either your `$HOME/.zshrc`, `$HOME/.bashrc`, or `$HOME/.profile`:

```
$ source path/to/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

With [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) installed, then install needed node versions, and finally set aliases to easily switch between versions.

For example:

```
 $ nvm install 0.8
 $ nvm install stable  
 $ nvm install unstable
 $ nvm install 0.9.21 
 $ nvm alias work 0.9.21 
 $ nvm alias legacy 0.8
```

When leaving off the patch number it installs the latest patch under that version, as do the keywords `stable` and `unstable`.

As of winter 2014 this installs and creates an alias to:

- the latest `v0.10.x` as `stable`.
- the latest `v0.11.x` as `unstable` (even/odd digit versions === stable/unstable).
- the final release `v0.8.x` as `legacy`.
- and the specified version `v0.9.21` as `work`.

To switch between versions: `nvm use alias`

- `nvm use work` would switch to 0.9.21 while `nvm use stable` would switch to the latest local `v0.10.x`, and [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) will complain if you try to use a version that has not been downloaded.

To check if there are more recent versions use: `nvm ls-remote`.

- This lists all available versions and highlights the ones currently installed.

To see the locally installed node versions: `nvm ls`

To uninstall [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) delete node related directories: `~/.nvm`, `~/.npm`, and `~/.bower`  with the standard  `$ rm -rf`

There is not a lot of magic in either library.

[NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) works by installing each version of node under `$HOME/.nvm/` and then symlinks the active version to the `.nvm/bin` directory, including any command-line tools installed globally via `npm -g`, which is provided to user's `$PATH`.

See the nvm's [usage](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage) section or n's [usage](https://github.com/tj/n#usage) section for an easy overview of the rest of the their commands .

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of `nvm` you can use the default aliases `stable` and `unstable`:

```
$ nvm install stable
$ nvm use stable
```